# Check Google compute VM instance state

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-compute-api

How can I check (inside Java code) if a VM instance on google compute engine is running or not? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method [`get`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get) and then check `status` in the response.

> **NOTE** The documentation page includes a way to "Try this API". If you have an existing project containing a VM instance, you can populate the form for your project and instance to see how it works.

See this example:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/cmdline/src/main/java/ComputeEngineSample.java

Although it doesn't use `instances.get`, it does use `instances.[insert|list|delete]` and it should give you a good template.